# Can't change dependencies

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I can't change dependencies in pubsepc.ymal file.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
    spritewidget:
```

I keep getting error: A dependency may only have one source. Why can't I change this. I am following https://github.com/spritewidget/spritewidget

Updated:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
      spritewidget :
```

Answer (score 0):

That's indentation issue. It should be 1 tab left indent not under sdk. Also try to run flutter packages get to resolve it later.

Comment: Thanks. But know i have the following error: Error on line 18, column 19 of pubspec.yaml: Mapping values are not allowed here. Did you miss a colon earlier?
      spritewidget:
                  ^

pub upgrade failed (65)

Comment: make sure you have space after colon

Comment: No you should left indent not right indent. Make spritewidget under flutter.